# Apple Touch Icon (Homescreen icon) for iPhone 7?

Tags: iphone, html, apple-touch-icon

I would like to provide a custum Homescreen Icon for iPhone devices. This is the code I have after my -Tag:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../img/apple-touch-icon-120.png" sizes="120x120" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../img/apple-touch-icon-144.png" sizes="144x144" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../img/apple-touch-icon-180.png" sizes="180x180" />
```

This is working fine on 6s but it not working on iPhone 7. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Apparently there are no differences between iPhone 6 and 7 regarding the Touch icon. And if there were, the iPhone 7 would probably support the legacy icons.

The error might be due to a caching issue of some kind. If you already visited the site with your iPhone 7 before the Touch icon was available, maybe your phone is simply too "lazy" to notice it immediately. It would be useful to retry with your iPhone 7, or to try with another iPhone 7.

Another useful check would be to [run RFG's checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker) against your site. It can spot several issues, like broken links or ill-formed images. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.